# SQL Left Join is duplicating value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables based on two columns. The left table has multiple records of unique combinations of the two columns, whereas the right table is distinct. When I do a simple left join, it is multiplying the values. Example below:

Table 1:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| JobID | PayID | Location |
+-------+-------+----------+
|   1   |   1   | Denver   |
|   1   |   1   | St Louis |
|   1   |   1   | Chicago  |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| JobID | PayID | Salary   |
+-------+-------+----------+
|   1   |   1   | 10,000   |
|   1   |   2   | 20,000   |
|   1   |   3   | 30,000   |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

I just did a simple
`SELECT * FROM table1, table2 LEFT JOIN ON table1.JobID = table2.JobID & table1.PayID = table2.PayID`

The result I am expecting is:

```
GOOD ONE
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------+
| JobID | PayID | Location        | Salary |
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------+
|     1 |     1 | Denver          | 10,000 |
|     1 |     1 | St Louis        | 10,000 |
|     1 |     1 | Chicago         | 10,000 |
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------+
```

but, instead, I am getting the salary multiplied (NOTE: this is just a simple example of what I'm doing, so the multiplier might not be correct because I actually have about 84 rows and it's multiplying by a factor of about 4,000):

```
BAD ONE
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------+
| JobID | PayID | Location        | Salary |
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------+
|     1 |     1 | Denver          | 30,000 |
|     1 |     1 | St Louis        | 30,000 |
|     1 |     1 | Chicago         | 30,000 |
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------+
```

Any help?

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, whichever).

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Sorry - this is using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the join is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.JobID = table2.JobID AND table1.PayID = table2.PayID;
```

In your case you probably don't even need an outer join, as I suppose you only want matches. So, remove the keyword `LEFT` from the query (or replace `LEFT` with the optional `INNER` keyword).

Comment: Thanks... I actually need all of the records from the first table. But will this display my Salary column? Or do I need to include that in the Select?

Comment: Why don't you try it? `SELECT *` selects all columns. You join `table1` with `table2` which gives you rows consisting of all columns from both tables. So, no, you don't have to explicitly say you want to see the salary column. But it is considered good style, not to `SELECT *`, but replace the asterix with the columns you actually want to select, e.g. `SELECT table1.JobID, table1.PayID, table1.Location, table2.Salary`. As to "I actually need all of the records from the first table": Are you saying there are rows in `table1` that don't have a match in `table2`?

Comment: Yes - there could be records in table1 that don't have a match in table2. And I'm focused more on why the value from the distinct table2 is multiplying.

Comment: I am surprised that SQL Server even accepts your query. It is invalid and should raise an error. `FROM table1, table2` is a cross join, i.e. the join of every table1 row with every table2 row. `LEFT JOIN ON table1.JobID = table2.JobID & table1.PayID = table2.PayID` has a lacking table name between `LEFT JOIN` and `ON`. The ampersand in your query would be a bitwise operator, which makes no sense in this place. Values cannot get multiplied unless you multiply them yourself or aggregate them (e.g. with `SUM`).